# Library giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, maven, retrofit

I have an internal library hosted on a maven repo. And it is being downloaded successfully and I am able to access it. But once I run the code, it crashes saying that the retrofit library that my library uses cannot be found.

Although the build was successful when deploying the internal library and it works when I run it through the code of the library by including it as a submodule rather than a maven dependency.

**EDIT**

Ok. So I was able to fix the crash by including the retrofit library in my main project as a dependency as well (which was weird)

But now I am confused regarding "implementation" and "api" in gradle file.
My Understanding was that if I have built a library using retrofit as "implementation", making available my library through maven. That retrofit library will be available when some use my library. But it seems like if you use "implementation", you have to explicitly include that retrofit library in your project dependency as well.

Should I be using "api" so that my library automatically includes retrofit so that the main project doesn't require it to be added?

Comment: send your crash log.

Comment: Usually it happens when You also need to add retrofit library to gradle file alongwith your library in your android studio project.

Comment: @mnp343 Yes I do, any solution for this? But I am using implementation . So I thought it should not be a problem.

Comment: @mnp343 Can you please see my edit and comment if you any idea about this.

Comment: "But it seems like if you use "implementation", you have to explicitly include that retrofit library in your project dependency as well" Nope.